# Why I couldn't ng serve my angular 4 application after I imported angularfire2 classes?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/Momo/Desktop/clientpanelapp/src/app/app.module.ts, found version 3, expected 4
    at StaticSymbolResolver.getModuleMetadata (C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\clientpanelapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31822:34)
    at StaticSymbolResolver._createSymbolsOf (C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\clientpanelapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31579:46)
    at StaticSymbolResolver.resolveSymbol (C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\clientpanelapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:31238:14)
    at StaticReflector.findSymbolDeclaration (C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\clientpanelapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:30355:67)
    at StaticReflector.findDeclaration (C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\clientpanelapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:30330:21)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\clientpanelapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:51:37)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\clientpanelapp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\clientpanelapp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:207:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\Momo\Desktop\clientpanelapp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:443:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you supplied some of the code that is causing this error.

Comment: Let me know if my answer below works - I got this error when I upgraded to Angular 5. Happy to revise my answer if you post more details about what you're trying to achieve, and what you did immediately before you got this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to one of your Angular packages being out of date.

I had this error when I updated my project to Angular 5, but did not update the version of the `@angular/cli`, but I think having other packages that are out of date will throw the same error.

Here's a list of dependencies for your `package.json` that should resolve this error if you're aiming to upgrade to Angular 5:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.34",
    "codelyzer": "^3.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
```

See the this [issue on the Angular Material 2 repo](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8229) on Github for more info.